# Как сделать так, чтобы на определённою команду бота была своя роль?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть команда на очистку

```
@Bot.command( pass_contet = True )

async def clear( ctx, amount = 100 ):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
```

И я хочу чтобы ею могли пользоваться только Админы и Модераторы.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chatmember.html

Answer (score 1):

Кто по вашему админы и модераторы? 1 из подходящих вам вариантов написали в комментариях.

Другой же вариант основан на том, что вы сделаете базу данных(или просто файл) с перечислением ID админов. И при каждой отправке клавиатуры проверять их роль, менять клавиатуру под их роль. Так же роль проверять следует во время обработки запроса.